# An urn contains $n$ marbles, one of which is white

Tags: probability, statistics

An urn contains $n$ marbles, one of which is white. If we extract $k$ marbles one
at a time, in such a way that in each extraction the probability of extracting any
some remaining marbles is the same, what is the probability that the white marble is extracted?

**Solution**. Each of the possible $\binom{n}{k}$ sets is extracted in an equiprobable way, therefore:

$P ($the white ball is extracted$) = \frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}}=\frac{k}{n}$

I don't understand most of the formula used. Can someone explain it for me?

Comment: The answer below explains the formula used. However, this problem can be solved without the hypergeometric distribution -- compare it to this problem: suppose you are one of 10 people of whom 5 will be randomly chosen for a free trip. Wha is the probability that you get chosen? Can you see the answer is 1/2? What if there were 12 people of whom 5 are chosen? How about $n$ people of whom $k$ are chosen?

Answer (score 1):

The formula that is used is based on [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

---

As and example: let it be that an urn contains $4$ white bals and $7$ black balls.

If we draw $5$ balls without replacement then what is the probability that $2$ of them are white and $3$ are black?

Answer:$$\frac{\binom42\binom73}{\binom{11}5}$$

---

In your question you are dealing with an urn containing $1$ white marble and $n-1$ non-white marble.

If we draw $k$ marbles without replacement then what is the probability that $1$ of them are white and $k-1$ are non-white?

Answer:$$\frac{\binom11\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}k}$$